# Dit-on plutôt «Qui a été le premier à travailler à votre rapprochement/au rapprochement entre vous et Marcel/de vous et de Marcel »

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, style-de-rédaction, écriture

Contexte:

Je m’adresse à Sylvain, l’une des personnes en question, qui m’a fait part d’un rétablissement de liens amicaux qui existaient entre lui et Marcel. Je lui demande donc qui est à l’origine de cette réconciliation, autrement dit je cherche à savoir qui a fait le premier pas.

Qui a été le premier à travailler à votre rapprochement.
Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement de vous et de Marcel.
Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement entre vous et Marcel.
Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement de vous avec Marcel.

Il en va de même avec le nom « réconciliation ».

Merci!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les deuxième et quatrième propositions ne sont pas très idiomatiques. La troisième est la meilleure mais reste assez lourde :

> Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement entre vous et Marcel.

Quelques variantes:

> Qui a pris l'initiative du rapprochement entre vous deux / de votre réconciliation ?

Si tu ne vouvoies pas Sylvain :

> Qui a pris l'initiative du rapprochement entre toi et Marcel ?

*Faire le premier pas* cité dans la question est bien aussi :

> Qui de vous deux a fait le premier pas ?

Dans un langage plus soutenu :

> Lequel d'entre vous a initié votre réconciliation ?

Comment: Bonjour jilliagre, «qui » est employé au sens de «qui de vous deux », il n’est pas question d’une troisième ni d’une quatrième personne dans le contexte, il s’agit de savoir qui, de Marcel ou de Sylvain, a rendu possible leur rapprochement. Merci.

Comment: Oui, pourquoi cette précision ? C'était déjà clair dans la question.

Comment: Il m’est venu à l’idée qu’il était possible que la tournure des phrases citées dans les détails laisse entendre qu’il y avait plus de deux acteurs en jeu et que l’agent de la réconciliation puisse ne pas être l’un des deux participants nommés

Comment: Mon esprit a tendance à « suranalyser » à la tombée de la nuit.

Comment: Mais je dois admettre avoir une préférence pour tes deux dernières propositions, elles semblent plus concises et élégantes.

Comment: Ah oui, je comprends. Les premières phrases permettent en effet cette interprétation mais elles seraient j'imagine écartées par le contexte du récit.

Answer (score 0):

- Qui a été le premier à travailler à votre rapprochement.
- Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement de vous et (de) Marcel.
- Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement entre vous et Marcel.
- Qui a été le premier à travailler au rapprochement de vous avec Marcel.

Toutes les possibilités sont correctes ; s'il est question de Marcel dans ce qui précède, les trois dernières phrases ne conviennent pas et une phrase de plus est acceptable.

- Qui a été le premier à travailler à votre rapprochement avec lui.

Le verbe « travailler » est peut-être un peu trop fort ; il se conçoit assez bien dans le contexte du rapprochement de deux pays, par exemple, ou de deux organisations, mais dans le cas de deux personnes il semble que ce terme connote une action peut-être trop intéressée, trop déterminée et calculatrice. Des termes tels que « favoriser », « agir en faveur de », « rendre possible » seraient possiblement préférables.

Comment: Salut LPH, dans le contexte j’écris « qui » au sens de «qui de vous deux ». Je m’adresse à Sylvain et Marcel n’est pas avec nous.

Comment: @user25275 Bonjour. La question serait à propos de la phrase ajoutée ; il me semble que l'on peut toujours dire « Qui de vous deux a été le premier à travailler à votre rapprochement avec lui. ». Pourquoi « lui » ne serait pas aussi l'un des deux ?

Comment: Il n’est point question ni d’un troisième ni d’un quatrième acteur dans le contexte, je veux tout simplement déterminer qui, de Sylvain ou de Marcel, a pris l’initiative de leur rapprochement. Il faut savoir que Sylvain est mon voisin de palier et que c’est à l’occasion d’une rencontre fortuite entre lui et moi sur le balcon du bloc qu’il m’a rapporté cette information. Comme Sylvain est un homme plutôt asocial, vivant en marge de la société, ses propos m’ont surpris pour ne pas dire qu’ils m’ont rendu perplexe et j’ai cherché approfondir la situation.

Comment: @user25275 En quoi, précisément, est-ce qu'un troisième ou quatrième participant serait impliqué ?

Comment: C’est une intuition qui a traversé mon esprit, il est tard...Alors dans les toutes les phrases que vous m’avez proposées il n’est question que de deux participants, n’est-ce pas?

Comment: @user25275 Oui, c'est ce que je crois, mais évidemment, parfois, si rarement, ce que l'on croit dur comme fer se trouve être faux, alors continuez quand même à vous poser la question.

Comment: Il m’est venu à l’idée qu’il était possible que la tournure des phrases citées dans les détails laisse entendre qu’il y avait plus de deux acteurs en jeu et que l’agent de la réconciliation puisse ne pas être l’un des deux participants nommés.

Comment: @user25275 Je ne pense pas, mais la possibilité suivante devrait éliminer vos doutes, du moins, les diminuer significativement : « Votre réconciliation avec Marcel est-elle le résultat d'un premier geste de vous ou de Marcel ? »